# kendo observable with variable

Tags: kendo-ui, observable

Why does this work (putting the JSON directly into the observable function)

---

```
<ul data-template="ul-template" data-bind="source: Orders">
</ul>
<script id="ul-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <li>
        OrderNo: <span data-bind="text: OrderNo"></span>
        name: <span data-bind="text: CustName"></span>
    </li>
</script>
<script>

var viewModel = kendo.observable({Orders:[
{"OrderID":"437","OrderNo":"1211","CustCode":"1022","CustName":"Kingmen"},{"OrderID":"438","OrderNo":"1212","CustCode":"1023","CustName":"Fredrick"}
]});

kendo.bind($("ul"), viewModel);
</script>
```

---

But this code does not work (with JSON data in a variable).  No output.

---

```
<ul data-template="ul-template" data-bind="source: Orders">
</ul>
<script id="ul-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <li>
        OrderNo: <span data-bind="text: OrderNo"></span>
        name: <span data-bind="text: CustName"></span>
    </li>
</script>
<script>

var orderData = '{Orders:[
{"OrderID":"437","OrderNo":"1211","CustCode":"1022","CustName":"Kingmen"},{"OrderID":"438","OrderNo":"1212","CustCode":"1023","CustName":"Fredrick"}
]}';
var viewModel = kendo.observable(orderData);

kendo.bind($("ul"), viewModel);
</script>
```

---

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Your orderData variable is a string and not JSON. Remove the quotes.

```
var orderData = {Orders:[]}
```

not

```
var orderData = '{Orders:[]}'
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JFlox/4swo988m/)